# Nuxt.js: Managing several websites/domains in 1 project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

let's say we have `website A`, `website B`, `website C`. They will all be on their own domain (`mypage-a.com`, `mypage-b.com`, `mypage-c.com`). The framework used is nuxt.js.

However, all 3 websites should have access to the same `/components` dir. Therefore, it would make sense to be able to have the same project for all 3 websites.

How could we set this up best? It seems like we have to temper a lot with the default settings. Important things to mention:

- our websites are all 100% static (no SPA, no SSR)
- we only use `<a>` tags, no `<nuxt-link>`
- the same `/components` dir should be available to all 3 subprojects

Comment: Run those 3 with different port

Answer (score 9):

We solved it like this:

- 1 repository for all projects together
- In a directory `projects`, we defined all the subprojects we need, all with their own `nuxt.config.js`
- Shared components are in the root directory
- Other shared code (`nuxt.config.base.js`, css etc) goes into the root directory, end gets extended by the subprojects if needed

```
|-components
|-projects
  |-A
    |-components
    |-pages
    |-nuxt.config.js
    |-...
  |-B
    |-...
|-nuxt.config.base.js
```

Comment: That's actually quite interesting. Could you please share how you use your nuxt.config.js and nuxt.config.base.js. 
Also, do you use different repositories for each project, plus a main one for the shared items (ignoring the "projects" folder? 
Thanks

Comment: It is a private repo, so unfortunately I can not share it. But to answer your questions:
1. we use 1 repo for all projects, it is roughly structured as in the answer
2. every project has a nuxt.config.js, that extends a base config in the root dir which has all shared settings. if using env-vars, you can actually move pretty much all configs to the root one
3. there are npm scripts for each of the projects, eg `"a:generate": "nuxt generate --config-file projects/a/nuxt.config.js",`
4. things that are global (components, scss mixins etc) are in the root dir and accessable by each project

Comment: @Beppe can you tell me what you have put in ```nuxt.config.base.js``` ?

Answer (score 2):

If they are fully static and will always use the same components, you can have 3 different projects but symlink the 'components' directory from a 'master/sharedcomponents' directory.

You then need to npm run generate each project after editing components, but that should be about it.

I've done a similar thing. Although it seems interesting, make sure your projects are really tightly relationed, or else it may bring more problems.